# Efficiently update an identical array on all tasks with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I'd like to improve the efficiency of a code which includes updates to every value of an array which is identical on all processors run with MPI. The basic structure I have now is to memcpy chunks of the data into a local array on each processor, operate on those, and Allgatherv (have to use "v" because the size of local blocks isn't strictly identical).

In C this would look something like:

```
/* counts gives the parallelization, counts[RANK] is the local memory size */
/* offsets gives the index in the global array to the local processors */

memcpy (&local_memory[0], &total_vector[0], counts[RANK] * sizeof (double));
for (i = 0; i < counts[RANK]; i++)
  local_memory[i] = new_value;

MPI_Allgatherv (&local_memory[0], counts[RANK], MPI_DOUBLE, &total_vector[0], counts, offsets, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

As it turns out, this isn't very efficient. In fact, it's really freaking slow, so bad that for most system sizes I'm interested in the parallelization doesn't lead to any increase in speed.

I suppose an alternative to this would be to update just the local chunks of the global vector on each processor and then broadcast the correct chunk of memory from the correct task to all other tasks. While this avoids the explicit memory handling, the communication cost of the broadcast has to be pretty high. It's effectively all-to-all.

***EDIT: I just went and tried this solution, where you have to loop over the number of tasks and execute that number of broadcast statements. This method is even worse.***

Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding this correctly: Each processor needs to make an update to a specific portion of the vector. And all processors need to eventually get the updates from all other processors? (since they are supposed to be the same)

Comment: I was just about to post an answer on how it can be better or worse, and you answered it yourself. I'm out of ideas. It might be possible hack around with custom MPI datatypes, but I'm not too familiar with those.

Comment: Yeah, I do actually use custom datatypes in my MPI statements, I just posted a simple version of the idea above. The gather might be able to be made faster using larger blocks, but I think primarily the issue is the constant need to copy the global vector to local memory on each processor. That's a lot of work. Fundamentally the best option is to just distribute the array, but unfortunately the rest of my code can't yet support that, so I'm looking for magic. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you describe is "all to all."  Each rank updates part of a larger array, and all ranks must sync that array from time to time.

If the updates happen at controlled points in the program flow, a Gather/Scatter pattern might be beneficial.  All ranks send their update to "rank 0", and rank 0 sends the updated array to everyone else.  Depending on the array size, number of ranks, interconnect between each rank, etc....this pattern may offer less overhead than the Allgatherv.